# How to Stop Fragments on a Tabbed View from Blinking when Refreshing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have app that is primarily for viewing documents. The documents are displayed in an html WebView and can are placed in a tabbed view so the user can swipe left/right to view the documents on their current page.

The users have the option to change the text size and the appearance of the documents they are viewing (night, light, and sepia mode), so basically a simpler version of the same idea as the kindle appearance editor. The appearance options come up as a pop-up window over their current document. I want them to be able to select an option and instantly see the change.

**As my app is now**, when the user selects one of the appearance options, all of the fragments are "refreshed" using the below code. All of the pages on the current activity successfully update such that I can swipe between documents though the tabbed view and see the selected change in all of them. **The issue I have** with my implementation is that the "refresh" caused the current fragment/activity to "blink." I believe this is due to detaching, attaching, and then committing the fragments on the current activity.

Bellow is my current implementation of refresh...

```
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Refreshes all the fragments (tabs) of the current Document activity.
 ***********************************************************************************************/
public void refreshAll()
{
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    SparseArray<Fragment> fragmentSparseArray = adapter.getRegisteredFragment();

    for(int i = 0; i < fragmentSparseArray.size(); i++)
    {
        ft.detach(fragmentSparseArray.get(i));
        ft.attach(fragmentSparseArray.get(i));
    }

    ft.commit();
}
```

Here is what I have tried...

I've tried replacing the detach and attach with...

```
ft.replace(R.id.htmlView, fragementSparceArray.get(i), "htmlView")
```

But I couldn't get it to work with that although I think that may be because I am using it wrong...

I have also tried to using overridePendingTransition(0,0) in a number of different places including...

Before and after ft.commit()

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
ft.commit();
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

Before and after the detach and attach...

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
ft.detach(fragmentSparseArray.get(i));
ft.attach(fragmentSparseArray.get(i));
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

And a combination of both... I have also tried applying...

```
addToBackStack(null)
```

after detaching and attaching.

The last thing I tried to do is add...

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
```

to the fragment and ViewPager xml layouts.

None of those made any changes. I will be interested in any recommendations!

Thank you.